# Sizing Images for Use in Bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, header, containers, fluid

I'm using Bootstrap for the first time and trying to implement it with an existing site of mine. I am using the default fluid container widths which I have read to be 724px and 1170px wide depending on your viewport. Maybe it sounds silly, but I'm just trying to grasp the concept here. Is 1170px the widest the site will ever show up, no matter what size screen the site is being shown on? Is it best to make my my banner image 1170px wide, or should it be larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width is set at 1170px, there's no need for a banner larger than 1170px.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you set a `width: 1170px` property to your container you will defeat the purpose of a fluid responsive design.

What I think you need to do here is set a `max-width: 1170px` to your container so it doesn't stay fixed at 1170px and it only maxes out at 1170px.

As for the question regarding the size of the banner, I would suggest you don't make it larger than that if you are setting the limit like @adam_bear says.